# Google Compute Instance RDP Fails (after working for years)

Tags: google-compute-engine, windows-server-2012-r2, rdp

Apologies if this is a bit basic:

I have a Google Compute Instance running Windows Server 2012 R2. It has a valid admin account and password (checked via gcloud). The external IP address can be pinged, the system has been stopped and started successfully. The gcloud commands execute successfully etc etc.

If I try to RDT in I get the unsuccessful message. If I use the RDT (Chrome) option in the Google Cloud Platform admin page I get this message:

> In order to use the Chrome RDP Extension, you must configure VM
>   instance so that it has an external IP address, username and password.
>
> Note: You must configure the network firewall to open TCP port 3389 to
>   enable RDP access.

Note that ALL of the above are correct and confirmed.

I am sort of going round in circles, I've tried to use powershell on a windows system to RDT in to no avail. Again, using the built in Bash serial access I can get to the system and, for example, retrieve the admin account and password, BUT RDT FAILS.

I have tried using the powershell command Enter-PSSEssion... and I initially got a winrm error, apparently the IP address needs to be in trustedhosts. Fixed that and now I am getting a message that I need to verify that winrm is running on the destination computer, catch 22, that's why I'm using winrm, to access the destination computer.

Any ideas what I might try next?

Thanks.....

Comment: You might be missing to allow  tcp/5986 port from anywhere. As by default, upon creation of instance it allows 3389 but not WinRM. Check the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#powershell)

Answer (score 0):

create a `rdp` network tag for firewall rule, which allows `tcp:3389` ingress and and then apply it to the instance in question... someone (assuming you're at work) might have removed/edited these rules trough the console or gcloud command.

Comment: Thanks, I've already done that (and it has the default RDP from anywhere on TCP: 3389). Yet when I do a portscan it doesn't show tcp:3389 as OPEN

Comment: Apologies for the many comments. After a number of stop/reset/starts I managed to get in to an IP address that was essentially setup for JIRA (tried and failed before). I noted the RDT service was running, but set to manual. I changed that to automatic. I also verified that RDT was allowed (yes). I then did a port scan and found out that tcp:3389 was now indeed opened. So I then tried to get into the external GCI IP address. all went well negotiating credentials etc, but now sitting at Please Wait. I don't know if it's updating, but am loathe to cancel the login attempt.